# Newbie issue, no idea why my program does what it does and how to fix it

Tags: python, numpy

I have been coding in python for a little more than 2 weeks as part of a university class.

I will now attempt to describe what the program is meant to do, but it's a bit hard as my english seems inadequate.

In my class I am to write a function that takes a numpy array. The function should compile a list of numbers that have the same whole number before the decimal, but only if there are 3 or more numbers with the same whole number.

For example, if 1.4, 1.5 and 1.6 are in the list, all three will be compiled into the result list. If the input list were 2.3, 2.5, 3.5 then nothing will be compiled since there are no cases of the same whole number appearing three times.

My code looks like this:

```
def removeIncomplete2(id):

    ip = id
    for N in range(np.size(ip)):
        ip[N] = np.round(ip[N]-0.5,0)

    x = 0
       for N in range(np.size(ip)):

            for n in range(np.size(ip)):
                if ip[N]==ip[n]:
                    x = x + 1
            if x > 3 and x != 0:
                id = np.delete(id, id[N])

    x = 0

    id = id[id > 0]
    return id
```

The test i put in is:

```
removeIncomplete2(numpy.array ([1.3, 2.2, 2.3, 4.2, 5.1, 3.2, 5.3, 3.3, 2.1, 1.1, 5.2, 3.1])
```

)

It should return

```
[ 2.2 2.3 5.1 3.2 5.3 3.3 2.1 5.2 3.1]
```

but returns:

```
[ 1.  2.  2.  4.  5.  3.  5.  3.  2.  1.  5.  3.]
```

I am stuck, and any advice is welcome. I am new at this coding, and I have no idea why it spits out what it does, and I have no idea how to fix it.
Any help is much welcomed!

Comment: Well, if you `round`every number you certainly won't have anything like `2.2` or anything with a decimal part to work with.

Comment: Please take care to copy/paste Python code with the indentation intact.  The code in your question will fail with an `IndentationError` and not do anything.

Comment: Seems rather odd for a course to be introducing numpy to students who have only been programming for two weeks.

Comment: I'm I the only one who has no idea what the script is meant to be doing?  I've read the question twice and can't figure it out.  Maybe we should put this on the puzzle site and see if they can figure out what he means.  Enigmatic...

Comment: A couple numpy functions that you may want to look up and find helpful: `np.floor` which rounds _down_, and is clearer to use than `np.round(n-0.5, 0)`, or even `np.array(..., dtype=int)`; `np.bincount`, or `np.unique` with the `return_count` option, or `np.histogram` with `bins` set to `np.arange(id.max())`, each of which will count how many of each value you have. With those functions (along with indexing), you can do the entire process in just a couple lines.

Comment: In ordinary python, your first loop `for N in range(np.size(ip)): ip[N] = np.round(ip[N]-0.5,0)` is necessary. But with numpy, you can replace that entire thing with `ip = np.round(ip-0.5, 0)`, since numpy does calculations on each and every element automatically. Of course, `ip = np.floor(ip)` is better, as in my previous comment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think I get what you are asking for. Please check this. If it is what you want, we can clarify the original question more. It results in the numbers that you specified.

```
import math
import numpy

original_numbers = numpy.array([1.3, 2.2, 2.3, 4.2, 5.1, 3.2, 5.3, 3.3, 2.1, 1.1, 5.2, 3.1])
result_specification = numpy.array([2.2, 2.3, 5.1, 3.2, 5.3, 3.3, 2.1, 5.2, 3.1])


def remove_incomplete(numbers):
    whole_number_tracker = {}
    # track occurrences of each whole number
    for number in numbers:
        whole_number = int(math.floor(number))
        whole_number_tracker.setdefault(whole_number, []).append(number)
    # compile all numbers that have more than three of the same whole number
    result = []
    for whole_number, full_numbers in whole_number_tracker.items():
        if len(full_numbers) >= 3:
            result.extend(full_numbers)
    return result


result = remove_incomplete(original_numbers)
print(result)
print(result_specification)
```

Comment: Thank you! I appreciate your time! Sorry for the badly explained problem :)

Comment: @Jacqques no problem. I'm glad it works for you. By the way, why are you using numpy? It seems unusual to start using it so early in a university class.